# Qt, OpenGL Widget, no such slot

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, slot

I wanted to create a simple application where there's triangle generated using OpenGL and three push buttons changing that triangle color. The triangle is generated but unfortunately buttons don't work and I get errors saying:

> QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::redSlot(OGL) in
>   ..\buttonwidget\mainwindow.cpp:17 QObject::connect: No such slot
>   MainWindow::greenSlot(OGL) in ..\buttonwidget\mainwindow.cpp:20
>   QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::blueSlot(OGL) in
>   ..\buttonwidget\mainwindow.cpp:23

I have slots definitions:

```
void MainWindow::redSlot(Widget* w)
{
    w->setColor(red);
}

void MainWindow::greenSlot(Widget* w)
{
    w->setColor(green);
}

void MainWindow::blueSlot(Widget* w)
{
    w->setColor(blue);
}
```

They are changing variable declared in class Widget that changes color of a generated triangle. Here's class Widget:

```
class Widget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

    enum color c;

    void setColor(enum color color1);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

};
```

And then I connect slots to buttons in class MainWindow constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    layout = new QVBoxLayout();

    QWidget *w = new QWidget();
    setCentralWidget(w);

    w->setLayout(layout);

    Widget *OGL = new Widget();

    //OGL->c=green; - it was a test whether changing value of enum type variable c works
    //it works, changing it changes the color of a generated triangle

    redButton = new QPushButton(tr("Red"));
    connect(redButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(redSlot(OGL)));

    greenButton = new QPushButton(tr("Green"));
    connect(greenButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(greenSlot(OGL)));

    blueButton = new QPushButton(tr("Blue"));
    connect(blueButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(blueSlot(OGL)));

    layout->addWidget(OGL);
    layout->addWidget(redButton);
    layout->addWidget(greenButton);
    layout->addWidget(blueButton);
}
```

Here's slot declaration in header:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QVBoxLayout *layout;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private:
    QPushButton *redButton;
    QPushButton *greenButton;
    QPushButton *blueButton;

public slots:
    void redSlot(Widget*);
    void greenSlot(Widget*);
    void blueSlot(Widget*);

};
```

How should I make them work?

Comment: did you put the slots keyword before the declarations in the `MainWindow` header, if you did do a clean and rebuild

Comment: It has been a while since I used Qt, but I vaguely remember this error. Did you use the MOC compiler correctly? Did you define your slots correctly (using `public slot:` in the header)?

Comment: I propose you to learn some Qt basics, before flooding with such questions: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html . If you have some problems, you should provide an SSCCE with full code, that completely describes your problem, instead of posting some code fragments from your real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connects in QT are string-based, that means:

```
connect(redButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(redSlot(OGL)));
```

will not work, since you havent defined a slot "redSlot(OGL)", instead you would have to use

```
...SLOT(redSlot(Widget*)));
```

Moreover, it is possible to define a SLOT with less parameter but not with more, therefore your slot/connect has to look like

```
void redSlot();

connect(redButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(redSlot()));
```

if you need a pointer to the "Widget" you have to retrieve it from somewhere else.

Example: Define slot in "Widget"-class and change connect to:

```
connect(redButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), OGL, SLOT(redSlot()));
```

Comment: How can I affect my widget OGL then? I need to change value of a variable stored in it in order to change the color of a triangle and I couldn't come up with a different solution.

Comment: Define the slot in your "Widget"-class instead of the MainWindow, so you can directly access the relevant data. It would also be much cleaner (at least to me)

Comment: OK, that really makes sense. I've defined my slots in my Widget class but I still get error liket this:
No such slot MainWindow::greenSlot()
Which is suprising because greenSlot() is no longer in MainWindow class

Comment: You really should have a look at the documentation :-)... instead of using this at the "connect" you have to use the pointer to your Widget-class, i.e. "OGL" (Answer updated)

Comment: Yeah I guess I should really read thoroughly the documentation :)
Thanks for help, I'll start reading immediately.